# Alterando valor de um arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Estou com um problema no `CASE 4` do meu código, quero alterar o preço do filme chamando o `set`, Porém ele não altera. Creio q seja problema de lógica, sou iniciante.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    Scanner dados = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Filme> filme = new ArrayList<>();
    Filme filmeC = new Filme();

    System.out.println("1 - Cadastrar filme \n2 - Excluir por ID \n3 - Checar filmes cadastrados");
    int numeroOpcoes = dados.nextInt();

    switch (numeroOpcoes) {
        case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                System.out.println("Digite ID");
                int id = dados.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Digite Nome");
                dados.nextLine();
                String nome = dados.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Genero");
                String genero = dados.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Quantidade");
                int quantidade = dados.nextInt();

                System.out.println("Preço");
                double preco = dados.nextDouble();

                filme.add(new Filme(id, nome, genero, quantidade, preco));
            }
        //break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("entre com o ID para ser excluido");
            int idExcluir = dados.nextInt();
            Filme emp = filme.stream().filter(x -> x.getId() == idExcluir).findFirst().orElse(null);
            if (emp == null) {
                System.out.println("ID não existe");
            } else {
                filme.remove(emp);
                System.out.println("Removido com sucesso");
            }
        // break;
        case 3:
            for (Filme x : filme) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        // break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Digite o ID para modificar o preço");
            int idPreco = dados.nextInt();
            Filme valor = filme.stream().filter(x -> x.getId() == idPreco).findFirst().orElse(null);
            if (valor == null) {
                System.out.println("ID não existe");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Digite novo valor");
                double novoValor = dados.nextDouble(); // NÃO ENTENDO PQ NAO ALTERA AQUI
                filmeC.setPreco(novoValor);
                System.out.println("Valor alterado");
            }
            for (Filme x : filme) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
            break;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: As primeiras três linhas do seu código acabaram não aparecendo na pergunta. Por favor, altere ela para que as linhas apareçam dentro da estrutura de código.

Comment: Pelo o que eu pude perceber, na hora de alterar o preço do filme você usou o objeto 'filmeC', mas o objeto que referencia o filme cujo ID é igual ao informado pelo usuário é a variável 'valor'.

Comment: Eu nao consigo acessar o set pelo filme. Ai criei o filmeC, porem ele nao altera a lista do filme.

Comment: Eu rodei o seu código aqui, e fiz essa alteração (substituí 'filmeC' por 'valor') e consegui alterar o valor do Filme. Tente fazer essa mudança para verificar se o código roda. Sugiro que naquela repetição que mostrar os filmes, ao invés de fazer apenas "System.out.println(x)", faça "System.out.println(x.getPreco())" (getter da variável preço) para verificar apenas os preços dos filmes cadastrados.

Answer (score 0):

O seu erro acontece porque, na hora de realizar a alteração do preço, você está usando o objeto 'filmeC', enquanto que o objeto que referencia o objeto da classe filme cujo ID é igual ao informado pelo usuário é 'valor'. Para que o código funcione corretamente, substitua a linha

```
filmeC.setPreco(novoValor);
```

por

```
 valor.setPreco(novoValor);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema.